# How can I make these visually identical strings computationally equal?

Tags: r, string, stringi

### Context:

I'm looking to join two tibbles based on a character vector, but something has happened between `write.csv()` and `read.csv()` that has made them non-equivalent. In the reprex below, `str_cmp()` returns `0` (a 'match'), but in my actual project it was returning `-1` (Strings not comparable). I don't know why that's changed.

In any case `str_cmp()` is not much use to me, because `dplyr::left_join` joins on equal values and can't work with a function.

How can I **change** one of these strings so that `str1==str2` returns `TRUE`?
I need to be able to do this for an entire character vector so that I can do:

`dplyr::left_join(tibble1,tibble2,by = c("charVector1"="charVector2")`
where `charVector1` and `charVector2` are the columns from which `str1` and `str2` were pulled.

### Reprex:

```r
#DL 19/10/30
## Tryna work out why these strings aren't the same
#####################################################################

#Get strings from GitHub repo ---------------------------------------
read.table(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davelovellCARU/stringHelp/master/string1.txt"
) ->
  str1

read.table(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davelovellCARU/stringHelp/master/string2.txt"
) ->
  str2

# The strings are not equal -----------------------------------------
str1 == str2
#>       x
#> 1 FALSE
# But they look the same and the computer knows it ------------------
stringi::stri_cmp(str1, str2)
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: string2.txt is encoded ANSI and the string1.txt with UTF-8 w/o BOM. so the strings are not the same?

Comment: Ah thanks, super helpful. String encoding still a mystery to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

There's a neat function that does this: `stringclean::replace_non_ascii(string)`
I ran it on both strings and now they're the same. Just chuck it into a mutate and the tibbles will join.

Comment: For anyone referring to this now, the package has been renamed `textclean`